# CSS Animation not working on IE11

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

I have a mouse over / mouse out animation on a couple of divs that is running great in Firefox and Chrome. However in IE it just won't work. Does anyone has any ideas why as this was working before?

```js
var actual = 1;
var over = 0;
var over2 = 0;


function scrollleft() {

  if (actual == 1) {
    $("#vidstrip").animate({
      left: "-1060"
    });
    actual = 2;
    return;
  }
  if (actual == 2) {
    $("#vidstrip").animate({
      left: "0"
    });
    actual = 1;
    return;
  }

  stopAllYT();
}


function scrollright() {
  if (actual == 2) {
    $("#vidstrip").animate({
      left: "+0"
    });
    actual = 1;
    return;
  }
  if (actual == 1) {
    $("#vidstrip").animate({
      left: "-1060"
    });
    actual = 2;
    return;
  }
  stopAllYT();
}


$("#vidstop").on({
  'mouseenter': function() {
    overme();
  }

});

$("#vidstop").on({

  'mouseleave': function() {
    outme();
  }
});


//ARROWS OUT
function outme() {

  if (over == 1) {
    $(".leftnav").removeClass("lnavchange");
    $(".rightnav").removeClass("lnavchange2");

    $(".leftnav").toggleClass("lnavout");
    $(".rightnav").toggleClass("lnavout2");
    over = 0;
    //alert(over);
    //alert(over);
  }
  //alert('MouseOut');
  // handle mouse event here!
}



//ARROWS IN
function overme() {


  if (over == 0) {
    //remove old class
    $(".leftnav").removeClass("lnavout");
    $(".rightnav").removeClass("lnavout2");
    //add class
    $(".leftnav").toggleClass("lnavchange");
    $(".rightnav").toggleClass("lnavchange2");
    over = 1;
    //alert(over);
  }

}
```

```css
#subheader {
  font-family: verdana;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
#subcopy {
  font-family: verdana;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #000;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
#titlei {
  font-family: verdana;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 46px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
hr.undertitle {
  background: #bfbfbf;
  width: 150px;
  border: 0;
  height: 2px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#subcopy {
  line-height: 21px;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: verdana;
}
#subhead {
  line-height: 21px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 22px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: verdana;
}
#Stage {
  text-align: center;
  width: 1060px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
#slidercontainer {
  width: 1060px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}
#vidspeephole {
  width: 724px;
  height: 407px;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 4px;
}
#vidsholder {
  width: 2896px;
  height: 407px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}
.vids {
  width: 724px;
  height: 407px;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#rightpromos {
  height: 407px;
  width: 208px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 8px;
}
#rightarrow {
  height: 407px;
  width: 54px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  top: 50%;
  bottom: 50%;
  margin-left: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#leftarrow {
  height: 407px;
  width: 54px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  top: 50%;
  bottom: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.featuredpages {
  width: 208px;
  height: 133px;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.paging {
  top: 10px;
  position: relative;
  height: 15px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 100px;
}
.pbutton {
  float: left;
  background: #F0F0F0;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  display: block;
  box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
  border-radius: 30px;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  zoom: 1;
  text-align: -webkit-match-parent;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}
.paging a.active {
  background: #999 !important;
}
.paging a:hover {
  background: #000 !important;
}
#row1 {
  position: relative;
  width: 1060px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 440px;
}
#row2 {
  position: relative;
  width: 1060px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 60px;
}
promocopy1 {
  height: 31px;
  padding: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: rgba(52, 52, 52, 0.85);
  position: relative;
  top: -41px;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
}
#stack {
  height: 114px;
  width: 1060px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}
.edgeLoad-EDGE-1207420 {
  visibility: hidden;
}
#mainvidcontainer {
  width: 1060px;
  height: 698px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
#vidstrip {
  height: 626px;
  width: 2120px;
  position: relative;
}
#vidstop {
  height: 626px;
  width: 1060px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 0;
}
.thevids {
  position: relative;
  width: 1060px;
  float: left;
  height: 596px;
}
.vidscopy {
  width: 1060px;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #999;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-top: 4px;
}
#navis {
  z-index: 9;
  width: 1060px;
  height: 30px;
  position: relative;
}
.leftnav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 300px;
  left: -60px;
  height: 54px;
  width: 54px;
  background-color: #666;
  z-index: 1;
  border: #FFF;
  border: 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.rightnav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 300px;
  right: -60px;
  height: 54px;
  width: 54px;
  background-color: #666;
  z-index: 1;
  border: #FFF;
  border: 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.pagingtop {
  top: 8px;
  position: relative;
  height: 15px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 40px;
  z-index: 2;
}
.pbuttontop {
  margin-left: 50%;
  margin-right: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  background: #F0F0F0;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  display: block;
  box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
  border-radius: 30px;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  zoom: 1;
  text-align: -webkit-match-parent;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}
.pagingtop a.active {
  background: #999 !important;
}
.pagingtop a:hover {
  background: #000 !important;
}
.lnavchange {
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 0.3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -webkit-animation-name: example;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -ms-transform-origin: left: 100px;
}
@keyframes example {
  0% {
    left: -10px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  100% {
    left: 22px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
.lnavchange2 {
  animation-name: example2;
  animation-duration: 0.3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@keyframes example2 {
  0% {
    right: -10px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  100% {
    right: 22px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
.lnavout {
  animation-name: example3;
  animation-duration: 0.3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@keyframes example3 {
  0% {
    left: 22px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  100% {
    left: -80px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
.lnavout2 {
  animation-name: example4;
  animation-duration: 0.3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@keyframes example4 {
  0% {
    right: 22px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  100% {
    right: -80px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="mainvidcontainer">

  <div id="vidstop">
    <div class="leftnav" onclick="scrollleft()"></div>
    <div class="rightnav" onclick="scrollright()"></div>
    <div id="vidstrip">

      <div class="thevids">
        <iframe id="player" width="1060" height="596" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/kf03Z7iiIk?rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0&enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        <div class="vidscopy">Test Copy1</div>
      </div>

      <div class="thevids">
        <iframe id="player" width="1060" height="596" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/8a05WugVHFs?rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0&enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        <div class="vidscopy">Test Copy 2</div>
      </div>

    </div>


  </div>

  <div id="navis">
    <div class="pagingtop">
      <a class="pbuttontop" id="b1" onclick="anitop1(1)"></a>
      <a class="pbuttontop" id="b2" onclick="anitop1(2)" style="margin-left:10px;"></a>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Edit: all good now it was just the youtube video that was being overlayed in Internet Explorer.

Thank you
Nuno

Comment: No sure if it has anything to do with the problem, but you're using the same id for both iframes.

Comment: Also, -ms-transform-origin is deprecated since IE10

Comment: What version(s) of IE is it not working in?

Comment: What is not working? I'm testing it in IE11 and it looks like in Chrome.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help.
When you hover over the video, there is an animation in which a couple of navigation arrows come fading in from the edge of the videos.

This works for me only on Chrome and Firefox.

And I'm using IE11

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!
It was the youtube video that was in front of the nav arrows.
In order to fix this for IE I had to add the wmode property to the youtube url:

wmode=opaque

Thank you all!
Hope this helps other people!